# I want to create a cancel button to stop a running dispatcher process for long time

Tags: wpf

I have a method which calls API and gets data but some it takes to long to and keeps running if happens so, I want to implement a cancel button to stop this API

```
public void GetCustomersRequest()
    {
        RefreshCustomerList = Visibility.Visible;
        IsBusy = true;
        if (Sorting == "")
        {
            Sorting = "ID";
            Order = "Descending";
        }

        //503 error handling needs review
        POSDataAccess.ClientGetRequest(SearchText, ApplicationData.Instance.SelectedCourse.ID, Sorting, currentPage, pageSize, Order, xx =>
        {
            if (xx.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                LogoutonUnAuthorizedAccess();
                return;
            }

            if (xx.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerListResponseBody>(xx.Content);
                 App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    
                    var newPage = new ObservableCollection<CourseCustomer>(result.Record.ToList());
                    if (CourseCustomerList == null)
                    {
                        CourseCustomerList = new ObservableCollection<CourseCustomer>();
                    }
                    CourseCustomerList.AddRange(result.Record.ToList());

                    if(CourseCustomerList.Count>0)
                    {
                        HasRecord = Visibility.Visible;
                        HasNoRecord = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HasRecord = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        HasNoRecord = Visibility.Visible;
                    }

                    CustomerCurrentPage = (int)result.Page;
                    CustomerTotalPages = (int)result.TotalPages;

                    RefreshCustomerList = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    IsBusy = false;

                }));

            }
            else
            {
                RefreshCustomerList = Visibility.Collapsed;
                IsBusy = false;
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
            }
        });
    }

    public void cancel()
    {
        //I want to cancel the API request here
    }
```

I have a method which calls API and gets data but some it takes to long to and keeps running if happens so, I want to implement a cancel button to stop this API

Comment: Learn about [CancellationTokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-5.0). These won't magically cancel things, but they give you a mechanism to notify your action that cancellation was requested.

Comment: how do i implement it in my code